# How to Google reverse image search with Bitmap or Base64 Android Java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, google-image-search

I have a Java class that acquires a picture using the camera. The result of the activity is a bitmap.

I need to pass the bitmap to Google image search using an http request.

Here's the piece of code that gets the bitmap:

```
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
    Bundle bundle = result.getData().getExtras();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
    String base64 = encodeTobase64(bitmap);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    getRequest();
    postRequest(base64);
}
}
```

How do I implement a method to post a request to Google image search passing the bitmap as input?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how one would encode a bitmap base64. And you are shure google wants a bitmap? Or a base64 encoded bitmap? Or what?

Comment: Yes, I saw on Google apis that they're taking base64 as input, but it's not clear to me how to pass the image as http request input